# How can I automatically move rows and cells of info from one sheet to another using Apps Script?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Apps Script and need to move order information from one sheet to another sheet that tracks our inventory numbers. Here is a link to an editable example sheet that I have made:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IwogRMmc7R-MPtPPjFizyt4WAe7FIbOjhVBxfkO4II/edit?usp=sharing

From comment below: "I added in some color on both sheets to show the before and after. Rows 2-7 on the source sheet would transfer to rows 3-8 on the target sheet. The goal is to get rows 8-10 on the source sheet to rows 9-11 on the target sheet and populate the # of orders underneath the corresponding item name each column."

I have tried using the Query function but my problem is that we have "packages" that include multiple items. Essentially I need the target sheet to automatically add the info from the source sheet and then add the # of orders to the corresponding columns based on the item name and if its a package I need to add the # of orders to all three item columns. I am guessing there will be a series of "if" statements in the script but the part I am unable to figure out is the automatic transfer of info to the target sheet and the making of new rows in the target sheet.

Thank you so much in advance for any help provided and if there is an easier way to do this other than apps script please feel free to let me know! Thanks again!

Comment: The spreadsheet is helpful but it would be nice if you could show and example of what you want with before and after examples.  Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: The sheet I provided was intended to be the example but I didn't label it that way. I added in some color on both sheets to show the before and after. Rows 2-7 on the source sheet would transfer to rows 3-8 on the target sheet. The goal is to get rows 8-10 on the source sheet to rows 9-11 on the target sheet and populate the # of orders underneath the corresponding item name each column. 

Thank you for the helpful links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Submit Orders to Inventory Sheet**

I modified your forms a little by adding a column named Ordered which indicates Yes when an item has been submitted.  I also changed your Item1,Item2 and Item3 to Socks,Shoes and Pants which agrees with your inventory sheet.  There's nothing really complicated about it it simply loads the data in a row array and appends to the Inventory sheet and marks the Ordered column as Yes.  If customers don't purchase a Complete Package then the function checks the socks shoes and pants columns to see which ones are not blank and those that are not blank sent to the inventory sheet with the number in the orders column and placed in their respective columns on the inventory sheet.

```
function submitOrders() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
  var ish=ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
  var idx={hr:1,sr:2,hA:[],lc:9};
  idx.hA=sh.getRange(idx.hr,1,1,idx.lc).getValues()[0];
  idx.hA.forEach(function(e,i){idx[e.trim()]=i;})
  var oA=sh.getRange(idx.sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-idx.sr+1,idx.lc).getValues();
  oA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[idx.Ordered]!='Yes') {
      if(r[idx.Complete]=='Yes') {
        var row=[r[idx.SalesPerson],r[idx.CustomerName],r[idx.Date],r[idx.Orders],r[idx.Complete],r[idx.Orders],r[idx.Orders],r[idx.Orders]];
        ish.appendRow(row);
        sh.getRange(i+idx.sr, idx.Ordered+1).setValue('Yes');
      }else{
        var row=[r[idx.SalesPerson],r[idx.CustomerName],r[idx.Date],r[idx.Orders],r[idx.Complete],(r[idx.Socks])?r[idx.Orders]:'',(r[idx.Shoes])?r[idx.Orders]:'',(r[idx.Pants])?r[idx.Orders]:''];
        ish.appendRow(row);
        sh.getRange(i+idx.sr, idx.Ordered+1).setValue('Yes');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Sheets Before Running Script:

Orders:
[image]

Inventory:
[image]

Sheet After Running Script:

Orders:
[image]

Inventory:
[image]

[Sheet appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: This is great! It solves my problem perfectly. Can I ask one clarifying question?

What exactly does `var idx={hr:1,sr:2,hA:[],lc:9};` accomplish?

Comment: Nothing much. It's just a personal preference of mine.  I like to use it when I doing this indirect addressing of array indices with column names.